# Content gets deleted from a mountpoint after reboot

Tags: mount, fstab

I created a mount point in an existing setup with this command:

```
mount -o loop /comptel
```

and made an entry to `/etc/fstab` as well which looks like this:

```
#tmpfs   /comptel       tmpfs   defaults,loop,size=110,mode=1777,dev,exec,suid  0       0
tmpfs   /comptel       tmpfs   rw,nosuid,nodev,size=110,noatime,user,uid=1000,gid=1001,mode=1777   0       0
```

This looks in `df -kh` like this:

```
tmpfs           4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /comptel
```

But when i reboot the setup, contents from /comptel gets deleted. Can someone please help me with this issue? What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in Wikipedia:

> tmpfs is a common name for a temporary file storage facility on many Unix-like operating systems. It is intended to appear as a mounted file system, but stored in volatile memory instead of a persistent storage device.

Which means that the content is purely stored in RAM, so as soon as you power down your computer you loose everything in it.

This is a filesystem only to be used for short term storage, like caches.

If you need to keep files around you need to use one of your hard disks, through some partitions.
In very specific setup, to makes things faster, you can have something in `tmpfs` that is copied from the disk at startup, used there, and then copied back to disk at shutdown time. You still have the risk of loosing everything if you loose power (so such kind of setup is more seen on servers with backup power).

Comment: Hmm.. I shouldn't have used tmpfs. Actual issue is that i want a sustained, permanent partition on my already installed setup Which i named /comptel. For that only i did all this mounting and entry on fstab. Should i use 'parted'? Any procedure or a link to follow through would be great. Thanks!